# Find rows that occur only once, in two datasets

Tags: r, duplicates, unique

I have data as follows:

```
library(data.table)
datA <- fread("A B C
               1 1 1
               2 2 2")

datB <- fread("A B C
               1 1 1
               2 2 2
               3 3 3")
```

I want to figure out which rows are unique (which is the one with `3 3 3`, because all others occur more often).

I tried:

```
dat <- rbind(datA, datB)
unique(dat)
!duplicated(dat)
```

I also tried

```
setDT(dat)[,if(.N ==1) .SD,]
```

But that is `NULL`.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fsetdiff`:

```r
rbind.data.frame(fsetdiff(datA, datB, all = TRUE),
                 fsetdiff(datB, datA, all = TRUE))
```

In general, this is called an `anti_join`:

```r
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(anti_join(datA, datB),
          anti_join(datB, datA))

   A B C
1: 4 4 4
2: 3 3 3
```

---

Data: I added a row in `datA` to show how to keep rows from both data sets (a simple anti-join does not work otherwise):

```r
library(data.table)
datA <- fread("A B C
               1 1 1
               2 2 2
               4 4 4")

datB <- fread("A B C
               1 1 1
               2 2 2
               3 3 3")
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution

```
library(data.table)

datB[!datA, on=c("A", "B", "C")]

       A     B     C
   <int> <int> <int>
1:     3     3     3
```

Or (if you are interested in the *symmetric difference*)

```
funion(fsetdiff(datB, datA), fsetdiff(datA, datB))

       A     B     C
   <int> <int> <int>
1:     3     3     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr` option by filtering rows that appear once with a `group_by` and `filter`:

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
datA %>%
  bind_rows(., datB) %>%
  group_by(across(everything())) %>%
  filter(n() == 1)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#> # Groups:   A, B, C [1]
#>       A     B     C
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     3     3     3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>